# Apache CXF generates nil elements for options not chosen in xsd:choice, then fails schema validation

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, cxf

With CXF 3.1.3, my webservice client submits an invalid jaxb soap request.  It creates two nil elements when it should not. When I manually remove the two nil elements in a soapui test suite, the request body validates against the xsd schemas properly.

The schema portion...

```
<xsd:complexType name="RequestContentType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="structures:ObjectType">
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element ref="ilcs:MessageID" />
                <xsd:element ref="nc:CaseDocketID" />
                <xsd:element ref="nc:DateRange" />
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The generated invalid request portion ...

```
        <ns4:RequestContent>
            <ns4:MessageID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns2:CaseDocketID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ns2:DateRange>
                <ns2:StartDate>
                    <ns2:Date>2015-11-13-07:00</ns2:Date>
                </ns2:StartDate>
                <ns2:EndDate>
                    <ns2:Date>2015-12-22-07:00</ns2:Date>
                </ns2:EndDate>
            </ns2:DateRange>
        </ns4:RequestContent>
```

In the java7 code to build the request object, the date range is the only thing set in the RequestContentType object.  The other two choice options, messageId and caseDocketId, are unset.  At runtime, the messageId and caseDocketId are null.

```
    DateRangeType dr = new DateRangeType();
    dr.setStartDate(NiemConverter.toDateType(oldest.getSubmittedToHfs()));
    dr.setEndDate(NiemConverter.toDateType(newest.getSubmittedToHfs()));
    RequestContentType rct = new RequestContentType();
    rct.setDateRange(dr);

    StatusRequestType req = new StatusRequestType();
    req.setFIPSCode(proxy(fipsCode));
    req.setRequestContent(rct);
```

Can anyone suggest why CXF is building nil elements for null java references?  Or how to stop it?

The file below was generated by the maven cxf-codegen-plugin, in the "wsdl2java" execution goal.

```
package g.i.h.d.c.extension._1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import gov.niem.release.niem.niem_core._3.DateRangeType;
import gov.niem.release.niem.proxy.xsd._3.String;
import gov.niem.release.niem.structures._3.ObjectType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for RequestContentType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="RequestContentType"&gt;
 *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
 *     &lt;extension base="{http://release.niem.gov/niem/structures/3.0/}ObjectType"&gt;
 *       &lt;choice&gt;
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://dcss.hfs.illinois.gov/csidews/extension/1.0}MessageID" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://release.niem.gov/niem/niem-core/3.0/}CaseDocketID" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://release.niem.gov/niem/niem-core/3.0/}DateRange" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
 *       &lt;/choice&gt;
 *       &lt;anyAttribute processContents='lax' namespace='urn:us:gov:ic:ntk urn:us:gov:ic:ism'/&gt;
 *     &lt;/extension&gt;
 *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
 * &lt;/complexType&gt;
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "RequestContentType", propOrder = {
    "messageID",
    "caseDocketID",
    "dateRange"
})
public class RequestContentType
    extends ObjectType
    implements Serializable
{

    @XmlElement(name = "MessageID", nillable = true)
    protected String messageID;
    @XmlElement(name = "CaseDocketID", namespace = "http://release.niem.gov/niem/niem-core/3.0/", nillable = true)
    protected String caseDocketID;
    @XmlElement(name = "DateRange", namespace = "http://release.niem.gov/niem/niem-core/3.0/", nillable = true)
    protected DateRangeType dateRange;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the messageID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getMessageID() {
        return messageID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the messageID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setMessageID(String value) {
        this.messageID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the caseDocketID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCaseDocketID() {
        return caseDocketID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the caseDocketID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCaseDocketID(String value) {
        this.caseDocketID = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the dateRange property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link DateRangeType }
     *     
     */
    public DateRangeType getDateRange() {
        return dateRange;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the dateRange property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link DateRangeType }
     *     
     */
    public void setDateRange(DateRangeType value) {
        this.dateRange = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker resolved this for me.  Apparently, he has run into this issue a few times earlier.  He built a xsl file that strips nil elements.  Then I added the file as a resource bean to my jaxws client configuration, as an outbound xslt feature.  The xsl file transforms the outbound xml by stripping the nil elements.  saxon-8-dom.jar is a required dependency.  Now my outbound request validates properly and is accepted by the remote service.

Answer (score 0):

`cxf-codegen-plugin` generated code has `nillable="true"`, because of the definition of the element `CaseDocketID`, which is `nillable="true"`, see [XSD](http://release.niem.gov/niem/niem-core/3.0/niem-core.xsd]):

```
<xs:element name="CaseDocketID" type="niem-xs:string" nillable="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>An identifier used to reference a case docket.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

It is not possible to change `nillable` in a element reference, see [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#sec-src-element):

> 2 If the item's parent is not <schema>, then all of the following are true:
>
> 2.1 One of `ref` or `name` is present, but not both.
>
> 2.2 If `ref` is present, then no unqualified attributes are present other than `minOccurs`, `maxOccurs`, and `id`, and no children in the Schema namespace (`xs`) other than <annotation>.

Apache CXF webservice request is valid.